Get max of row in column in dataframes and keep information from different row
Hope some one can help me with this. I have several dataframes that contains a value a corresponding id and name. For each id I want the max value for all dataframes but I must also now for which name this max value occured.
The example only shows two dataframes but I really have about a 100 which also contains about a 100 id's so can't just take the max and then check which values are contained in one of the dataframes and take the name from there.
I have tried with groupby but can not get it to work.
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame()
d2 = pd.DataFrame()
d1['id'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
d2['id'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
d1['max'] = [10,20,30,40,50]
d2['max'] = 25
d1['name'] = 'name_1'
d2['name'] = 'name_2'
df_max_list=[d1, d2]
df_max_out=pd.concat(df_max_list).groupby(level=0).max()

Got the result:
    id  max name
0   1   25  name_2
1   2   25  name_2
2   3   30  name_2
3   4   40  name_2
4   5   50  name_2

Expected result:
    id  max name
0   1   25  name_2
1   2   25  name_2
2   3   30  name_1
3   4   40  name_1
4   5   50  name_1


You could use .idmax() to find the maximum value for max for each group.
# Concat and reset index
df_tot = pd.concat(df_max_list, ignore_index=True)
# Groupby on id and select index for maximum value of 'max' for each group
df_max_out = df_tot.loc[df_tot.groupby('id')['max'].idxmax()]

output:
   id  max    name
5   1   25  name_2
6   2   25  name_2
2   3   30  name_1
3   4   40  name_1
4   5   50  name_1


You can drop the indexes when doing the concatenation, i.e. pd.concat(df_max_list, ignore_index=True)

Thank you works great! Just think you have a typo in the df_max_out line

Thanks both. I fixed the typo and changed the concat to Daniel Mitre's suggestion

You could set id as index and use where:
tmp1 = d1.set_index('id')
tmp2 = d2.set_index('id')

out = out = tmp1.where(tmp1['max'].gt(tmp2['max']), tmp2).reset_index()

If your dataframes are already aligned on id, you could simplify the above to:
out = d1.where(d1['max'].gt(d2['max']), d2)

Output:
   id  max    name
0   1   25  name_2
1   2   25  name_2
2   3   30  name_1
3   4   40  name_1
4   5   50  name_1


Thank you, but how would this work with 100 dataframes? Wouldn't it be very slow?

@Regina I missed the fact that you have 100 dataframes, in this case better concat
